# Is it possible to define an __iter__ method for a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Suppose we have the following class:

```
class Klass:
    iterable_attr_names = {'x', 'y', 'z'}
    x = 5
    y = 6
    z = 7
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(*args): # 'foo' is not in iterable_attr_names
        return
```

Is it possible to define an `__iter__` method for the class, instead of only instances of the class? The implementation of the class `__iter__` method might look something like the following:

```
class KlassIter:
    def __init__(self, klass):
        self._klass = klass
        self._inner_it = iter(klass.iterable_attr_names)
    def __next__(self):
        attr_name = next(self._inner_it)
        return getattr(self._klass, attr_name)
```

Then we could do this:

```
print(Klass.x)
print(Klass.y)
print(Klass.z)
```

and this:

```
for attr in Klass:
    print(attr)
```

Comment: I believe you'd need to add an `__iter__` method implementation to your class's metaclass.

Comment: I would imagine those things would be specified in a metaclass, if at all!